# When setting new coordinates for MKPointAnnotation the pin disappears

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkpointannotation

When I try to move my MKPointAnnoatation like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            [user setCoordinate:coordinate];
```

The pin disappears on the map :( Is there a different solution to move a MKPointAnnotion?

EDIT MORE CODE:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D *plotLocation = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) *
                                              _trak.trakTagRelationship.count);

    int i=0;
    for (TrakTag* tag in _trak.trakTagRelationship)
    {

        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(tag.trakTagX.doubleValue,
                                                                           tag.trakTagY.doubleValue);
        plotLocation[i] = coordinate;


        i++;
    }

    TrakTag* dummy = [[_trak.trakTagRelationship allObjects]lastObject];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(dummy.trakTagX.doubleValue,
                                        dummy.trakTagY.doubleValue);

    if (user != NULL)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            [user setCoordinate:coordinate];

            NSLog(@"Annotaions:%@",user);

        }];
    }
    else
    {
        user = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
        [user setCoordinate:coordinate];
        [mapView addAnnotation:user];
    }


    line = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:plotLocation count:_trak.trakTagRelationship.count];
    [mapView addOverlay:line];
```

Comment: Did you try to set coordinate without animation? Does it get worked?

Comment: without animations I get the same problem

Comment: Are you sure that coordinate fits into the visible area?

Comment: What is your span and what are the coordinates?

Comment: coordinates are (54.f,8.f) and (55.f,8.f). Yes coordinates fit into the area.

Comment: Do you mean latitude 55 and longitude 8?  That's in the North Sea west of Denmark.

Comment: Jep, those coordinates are "simulated", I am not there at the moment I am testing

Comment: What method is this code in?  When does it get called?  Show more of the surrounding code.  You're saying the pin appears at 54,8 (North Sea) and disappears when this code runs?  Did you try zooming out to the whole world to confirm the pin is where you think it is?

Comment: Is `trakTagRelationship` an `NSSet`?  It looks like the code is updating the coordinate to the "last" object in `trakTagRelationship` but if it's an `NSSet`, there is no strict ordering of the objects.  You might not always get the last object added to the set (and so the pin is jumping to a previous location that you're not looking at).

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions, I don't know why but after:
1)Resetting the simulator 
2)Cleaning Build folder
3)Restarting mac+xcode
Everything worked, I should do this sort of thing every time before I ask a question :/